# fortran overloading interface error

Tags: overloading, fortran90, gfortran

I edit three files
first:add.f90

```
 module MA
  implicit none
   contains
    subroutine show_int(n)
      implicit none
      integer , intent(in) ::n
      write(*,"('n=',I3)") n
      return
    end subroutine show_int
     subroutine show_character(str)
      implicit none
       character(len=*) ,intent(in) :: str
       write(*,"('str=',A)") str
       return
    end subroutine show_character
end module
```

second: add.h

```
interface show
  module procedure show_int, show_character
end interface
```

third:main.f90

```
program main
   use MA
   implicit none
   include 'add.h'
   call show_int(1)
   call show(1)
   call show_character("Fortran 95")
   call show("Fortran 95")
   print * ,"hello "
end program
```

I compile ,gfortran add.f90 main.f90 -o main
I got these errors
    add.h:2.2:
       包含于 main.f90:4：
       module procedure show_int, show_character
       1
       错误： (1) 语句无法归类
       main.f90:6.13:
       call show(1)
             1
       错误： 泛型‘show’在(1)处没有特定的子进程
       main.f90:8.24:
       call show("Fortran 95") 1
       错误： 泛型‘show’在(1)处没有特定的子进程
I don't know why ?
can you help me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot read the error messages, but:

The `module procedure` statement can be used only inside the module containing the procedure. Forget the `.h` file and place the generic interface block into the module. In Fortran 2003 you could use just `procedure` (without `module`) and it should work.

Comment: Recently ,I find I can compile these codes with gfortran GNU Fortran (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3,but I cannot compile these with gfortran GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4).            In my station ,it install gfortran 4.4.6.Because the codes is download from web which interface block out the module,I can't edit the codes. I want compile these codes with gfortran 4.4.6,what should I do ?

Comment: you can install recent GCC on your own

Comment: That will install gfortran ,gcc ,mpi.I try ...Thank you.